# what are the value of these complex integrals

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

(i) I think it will $|z|={\pi\over 2}$, so the value will be $0$ as on that specified domain $\tan z$ is analytic.

(ii) I have no idea!Could any one help me?

(iii) at $z=2\pi i$ the integrand has a simple pole so the residue at that point is $1$ as I have calculated so the value of the integral will be $2\pi i$ by Residue Theorem.

(iv) at $z=0$ $\sin z$ has simple pole and by Residue Theorem the value of integral is $2\pi i$

Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Hint. The integrals can be solved using Cauchy's theorem, checking the poles (if any) of the integrand bounded by the given locus of points in $\mathbb C$.

For the one giving problems, i.e. number $(ii)$: as

$$\tanh z=\frac{e^z-e^{-z}}{e^z+e^{-z}},$$

then poles correspond to complex numbers $z=x+iy$ s.t. $e^z+e^{-z}=0,$ or

$$e^x e^{iy}+e^{-x}e^{-iy}=0,$$

i.e.

$$(e^x\cos y+e^{-x}\cos y)+i(e^x\sin y-e^{-x}\sin y)=0. $$

We obtain the solutions $\cos y=0$, $x=0$, i.e. all complex numbers $z$ s.t.

$$\operatorname{Re}(z)=0, $$
$$\operatorname{Im}(z)=\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi,~~k\in\mathbb Z.$$

The locus of points

$$|z-1|=2 $$

is a circumference of radius $2$ and center $1$ in the complex plane. Which poles of $\tanh z$ are contained in the above circle?